# Excel COUNTIF function limit

Tags: excel, countif

I have an Excel countif function on my product spreadsheet so when w product code appears more than once it starts counting from number 1.

The problem is when it gets to 9 it uses symbols and letters, this is what I'm trying to avoid in my spreadsheet.

Is it possible to get the countif function to count above 9 to double digits 10,11,12 etc.?

This is my formula, column B is where the product code appears

```
=CHAR(48+COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2))
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. I believe the COUNTIF is counting above 9 all right and that it's the `CHAR` that is converting those higher numbers to letters. Why are you using `CHAR` anyway?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem, but could you elaborate why just the normal countif function isn't working for you.  The formula looks right for what you're trying to do without the char function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just took out the char 48 and that worked fine guys. Thankyou for your help @jerry I wasn't sure if it was an essential part of the countif function.

So the updated formula is

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2)
```

Thanks, I love this place :-)